# Auto-increment with Group BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, auto-increment

I have two tables as follows:

**Contract**

[image: Contract] |

**Contractuser**

[image: Contractuser]

My job was to fetch **latest invoice date** for each contract number from Contractuser table and display results. The resultant table was as follows:

**Result Table**

[image: Result Table]

Now I wanted to get a auto-increment column to display as the first column in my result set.

I used the following query for it:

```
SELECT @i:=@i+1 AS Sno,a.ContractNo,a.SoftwareName,a.CompanyName,b.InvoiceNo,b.InvoiceDate,
b.InvAmount,b.InvoicePF,max(b.InvoicePT) AS InvoicePeriodTo,b.InvoiceRD,b.ISD
     FROM contract as a,contractuser as b,(SELECT @i:=0) AS i
     WHERE a.ContractNo=b.ContractNo
     GROUP BY b.ContractNo
     ORDER BY a.SoftwareName ASC;
```

But it seems that the auto-increment is getting performed **before the group by** procedure because of which serial numbers are getting displayed in a non contiguous manner.

Comment: You can't really have that work, since it does evaluate the variable for each row. What you need is a subquery to handle the grouping and then join the increment to the results.

Comment: For future reference, it's always best to provide your data in a plain text format, as it's easier to copy/paste it if someone wants to try and replicate your source data/results.

Comment: +user2366842 Point noted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP BY` and variables don't necessarily work as expected.  Just use a subquery:

```
SELECT (@i := @i + 1) AS Sno, c.*
FROM (SELECT c.ContractNo, c.SoftwareName, c.CompanyName, cu.InvoiceNo, cu.InvoiceDate,
             cu.InvAmount, cu.InvoicePF, max(cu.InvoicePT) AS InvoicePeriodTo, cu.InvoiceRD, cu.ISD
      FROM contract c JOIN
           contractuser as b
           ON c.ContractNo = cu.ContractNo
      GROUP BY cu.ContractNo
      ORDER BY c.SoftwareName ASC
     ) c CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @i := 0) params;
```

Notes:

- I also fixed the `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- I also added reasonable table aliases -- abbreviations for the tables.  `a` and `b` don't mean anything, so they make the query harder to follow.
- I left the `GROUP BY` with only one key.  It should really have all the unaggregated keys but this is allowed under some circumstances.

Comment: I just removed the SELECT @i:=@i+1 in the FROM clause and the query worked like a charm. Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

SELECT @row_no := IF(@prev_val = lpsm.lit_no, @row_no + 1, 1) AS row_num,@prev_val := get_pad_value(lpsm.lit_no,26) LAWSUIT_NO,lpsm.cust_rm_no
FROM lit_person_sue_map lpsm,(SELECT @row_no := 0) x,(SELECT @prev_val := '') y
ORDER BY lpsm.lit_no ASC;

This will return sequence number group by lit_no;